# In metric space, is (A')'= A'?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $A$ be a subset of a metric space $(M,d)$. Is $(A')'=A'$?

($A'=\{x|\forall\text{ nbd. }U\text{ of }x\ [(U\backslash\{x\}\cap A\neq\varnothing)]\}$)

I've taken two examples:

In $(\mathbb{R},||\cdot||)$, take $A=(0,1)$, then $A'=[0,1]$ and $(A')'=[0,1]$;

In a space with discrete metric, take $A=D(x,1)$, then $A'=(A')'=\varnothing$.

So I guess the statement is true for any set. But I can only prove $(A')'\subset A'$  and don't know how to prove $A'\subset(A')'$. (or just can not be prove since the statement is false? I don't know yet) Here is my proof:

**Proof:**

Lemma 1: $A'$ is closed.

Pf of Lemma 1: Let $x\in M\backslash A'$.

$x\notin A'\Rightarrow \exists r[(D(x,r)\backslash\{x\})\cap A'=\varnothing]\Rightarrow D(x,r)\backslash\{x\}\subset M\backslash A'$

$\because x\in M\backslash A'\ \therefore D(x,r)\subset M\backslash A'$

$\Rightarrow M\backslash A'$ is open $\Rightarrow A'$ is closed.

Lemma 2: $A$ is closed $\Rightarrow A'\subset A$

Pf of Lemma 2: Let $x\in M\backslash A'$.

$A$ is closed $\Rightarrow M\backslash A$ is open $\Rightarrow M\backslash A$ is a nbd. of every $x\in M\backslash A$.

$\because M\backslash A\cap A=\varnothing$ and $x\notin A$ $\therefore ((M\backslash A)\backslash\{x\})\cap A=\varnothing$

$\Rightarrow x\notin A'\Rightarrow (M\backslash A)\cap A'=\varnothing \Rightarrow A'\subset A$

By Lemma 1 and Lemma 2, obviously $(A')'\subset A'$.

Comment: Is $A’$ the set of limit points of $A$?

Comment: Try $A=\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb N\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every set $A$ in a metric space $A'$ is closed, so contains its limit points and $(A')' \subseteq A'$ follows.

Equality doesn't hold in general, consider (in $\Bbb R$, usual metric) the set $A=\{\frac1n: n=1,2,3,4\}$ which has $A'=\{0\}$ and $(A')'=\emptyset$, e.g.